# The procedure after spyProcedure is not being called ...How to resolve this

Tags: tsqlt

I am trying to use the spyProcedure , but it is not working as expected.
Below is the scenario please help me where am I doing wroing?

```
**CREATE PROC [dbo].[proc3](@id int , @marks int out)
as
begin
   select @marks = marks from student where id=@id;
end**


CREATE PROC [dbo].[proc4](@id int , @marks int )
as
begin
   print 'inside proc4 id ' + cast(@id as varchar) + ' marks ' +  cast(@marks as varchar);
   update student set marks = @marks where id=@id;
end


**CREATE PROC [dbo].[proc6](@id1 int , @id2 int) 
as
begin
      declare @marks int;
      EXEC tSQLt.SpyProcedure 'proc3' , 'SET @marks = 80';

    set @marks  = @marks + 20;
    print ' marks = ' + cast(@marks as varchar);
    EXEC proc4 @id  = @id2 , @marks = @marks;
end** 

EXEC proc6 @id1 = 1 , @id2 = 2;
GO
```

When I call the above , it is not able to execute/call the " EXEC proc4 @id  = @id2 , @marks = @marks;"  but when I comment "EXEC tSQLt.SpyProcedure 'proc3' , 'SET @marks = 80'; " then it is able to be executed.

Can you please help me where am I doing wrong and how to execute it correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you have fully grasped how to use tSQLt from your code example above.

To start with to run a basic tSQLt test you need to do a few things.

1. All tests need to be in a test class.

   EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'MyTestClass'
   GO
2. All tests must start with the key word 'test'

   CREATE PROCEDURE [MyTestClass].[test_MyFirstTest]
   AS
   BEGIN
     EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 1,1, '1 does in fact equal 1'
   END
3. To run a test you a test you use the tSQLt test runner

   EXEC tSQLt.Run '[MyTestClass].[test_MyFirstTest]'

Using SpyProcdure is an advanced feature and should really only be attempted once you have a clear understanding of the basics. If you are experience with TDD and mocking frameworks then it shouldn't be a massive leap to getting SpyProcedure to work.
If you feel you are comfortable with the basics first try to use SpyProcedure to record what  parameters the spied on procedure was called with using SpyProcedureLog (see the documentation at tSQLt.org) and then try returning a resultset.  What you are attempting in your example above (to pass back a value in a variable) is about as hard as you can get with tSQLt.

Comment: To echo Andrew's point, tSQLt.SpyProcedure isn't designed to be used outside of a tSQLt test. There's a detailed [tSQLt.SpyProcedure example available on the user guide](http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/isolating-dependencies/spyprocedure/) which may help you.